# Why does finding my role by name return undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

```
Gang.findOne({leaderUserID: message.author.id, leaderUserName: message.member.user.tag, serverID: message.guild.id}, (err, gang) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Gang")
        .setColor("4000FF")
        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
        
        gangName = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(" ") + 1, message.content.length);

        if(!gang){
                const newGang = new Gang({
                leaderUserID: message.author.id,
                leaderUserName: message.member.user.tag,
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                gangName: gangName,
                points: "1"
            });

            guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                name: gangName,
                color: `GREY`
                },
                reason: `Gang created by ${message.member.user.tag} at ${message.timestamp}`
            });
            

            
            let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(guild => guild.name === gangName);
            
            console.log(`role = ${role}`);
            member.roles.add(role);

            
            
            newGang.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
            
            
            embed.addField("Gang Creation", "-15 points", true);
            embed.addField("Gang Name", gangName, true);
            message.channel.send(embed);

            return;
```

Everything works except assigning the role. I set the gang name to the second part of the command, I create the role with that name, I set the role to
`let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(guild => guild.name === gangName);`
but then, the console.log of role shows "undefined".

How is it undefined? I just created the role and then searched for it.

Comment: guild.roles.create is an async function that returns a promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You need to await that promise before the role creation is completed.

Comment: @KurtThiemann So, would I my let role = message.guild... into the roles create?

Comment: @KurtThiemann or would I throw a ```.then(let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(guild => guild.name === gangName))``` on it

Answer (score 2):

guild.roles.create is an async function so you can use `await`

```js
let role = await guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: gangName,
        color: `GREY`
    },
    reason: `Gang created by ${message.member.user.tag} at ${message.timestamp}`
});

console.log(`role = ${role}`);
member.roles.add(role);
```